# Expected type utf8 for Argument 'sql' but got type 'object'

Tags: javascript, gnome, gjs

I'm trying a [GNOME JavsScript tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/record-collection.js.html.en), that seems [not to work in its original version](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/javascript-list/2013-February/msg00009.html).

```
  var gdaStrConn = Gda.Connection.open_from_string("SQLite", "DB_DIR=" + GLib.get_home_dir () + ";DB_NAME=gnome_demo", null, 0);
  print('Connected');
  gdaStrConn.execute_non_select_command (this.connection, 'create table demo (id integer, name varchar(100))');
```

The documentation for the function `execute_non_select_command`, says:

```
gint                gda_connection_execute_non_select_command
                                                        (GdaConnection *cnc,
                                                         const gchar *sql,
                                                         GError **error);
This is a convenience function to execute a SQL command over the opened connection. For the returned value, see gda_connection_statement_execute_non_select()'s documentation.

cnc : an opened connection
sql : a query statement that must not begin with "SELECT"
error : a place to store errors, or NULL
Returns : the number of rows affected or -1, or -2
```

Now I get the following error.:

```
(gjs:25295): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: Error: Expected type utf8 for Argument 'sql' but got type 'object'
```

Why I get that error, cause the `sql` param is a string: `'create table demo (id integer, name varchar(100))'`?

What is wrong with that call?

Answer (score 1):

On line 3 omit the first argument in your function, so the line would look like this:

```
gdaStrConn.execute_non_select_command ('create table demo (id integer, name varchar(100))');
```

I don't know why this works, just learning gjs myself.

Comment: The reason this works is that the documentation is for the C version of the library. The first argument, the pointer to a `GdaConnection`, is represented in javascript with the object the method is being called on (i.e. `gdaStrConnection.execute_non_select_command(...)` is roughly equivalent to the C `gda_connection_execute_non_select_command(gdaStrConnection, ...)`)